# What is wrong with this yii statement.?

Tags: php, yii

I have the following codes in my contoller which retrives all the data from the table...Its working fine when I use find instead of findAll... using findAll its showing  error 'array to string conversion'.Is there any other way to write the query..

// Posting the full contoller Code//

```
    public function actionSearch()
    {
         $model = new SearchEmployee();

           /*Getting Data From Search Form For Processing */
          if (isset($_POST['SearchEmployee'])) {

          $category   =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['category_id'];
          $skills     =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['skills'];
          $experience =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['experience'];

         $model = SearchEmployee::model()->findAll("category_id=:category AND
             key_skills like :skill AND experience=:experience", array(
                 'category'=>$category,
                 'skill'=>'%'.$skills.'%',
                 'experience'=>$experience
             ));
          //var_dump($model);  
         $this->render('search', array('model' => $model));
       }
}
```

//view:search.php:This is my view section it is  being used for searching and displaying the results  //

## Search Employees

```
<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p> 

   <div class="row">
     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Category');   ?>
     <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'category_id',$list,array('empty' =>'(Select a Category')); ?>
     <?php echo $form->error($model,'category'); ?>
</div>

    <div class="row">
 <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Experience'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->textField($model,'experience'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($model,'experience'); ?>  
</div>

    <div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Skills'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->textField($model,'skills'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($model,'skills'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Search'); ?>
</div>



 <div class="view">

   <h1>Results </h1>

 <div class="view" id="id">

   <h4>Name :      <?php echo $model ->name;    ?></h4>
   <h4>Skills:     <?php echo $model ->key_skills; ?></h4>
   <h4>Category:   <?php echo $model ->category; ?></h4> 
   <h4>Experience: <?php echo $model ->experience; ?>&nbsp;Years</h4>  
   <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('VIew Details'); ?> </h5>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Is there any other way to write the query...Its still working as have used var_dumb to see the result.

Comment: The error is fairly explicit.  `$model` is an array of items yet you are using it (or part of) like a string.  There's nothing in the controller that stands out.  What is your **search** view doing with the variable?

Comment: what does your view code look like? I'm guessing that you are trying to access an attribute directly (in the view), rather than through the record collection.

Comment: @Emissary,@adamS...Just edited my question..have include my view..kndly do have  a look.

Comment: Using `find()` finds *one record*, using `findAll()` finds *an array of records*. If you want to display a list of records, your view needs to loop over that list...

Comment: @DCoder...can u pls tell me how to write that.

Comment: @DCoder..I have alredy tried ur solution.like below answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not great to put logic like this inside your view but it may help to debug..

replace your results section with this loop in your view and see if it's where your problem lies.

```
<div class="view" id="id">
    <?php 
        if(count($model)) {
            foreach($model as $record) {
                echo "<h4>Name : " . $record->name . "</h4>";
                echo "<h4>Skills : " . $record->key_skills . "</h4>";
                echo "<h4>Category : " . $record->category . "</h4>";
                echo "<h4>Experience : " . $record->experience . "</h4>";
                echo "<h5>" . CHtml::submitButton('VIew Details') . "</h5>";
            }  
         }
     ?>
</div>
```

Comment: have tried this..its showing error  "Trying to get property of non-object". on  echo "<h4>Name : " . $record->name . "</h4>";

Comment: i edited it. looks like you didn't have any results returned from your query.

Comment: it's not showing any results? or you get the array to string conversion error still?

Comment: now it is not displaying the search screen...getting error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: you join me here if u have soutionn http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50940/yii-framework

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about `CGridView` to display tabular information from db (or other arrays).

Based on your question, I think you should use gii tool to generate some crud files on your models. That would give you many code samples to learn from. You can activate gii by uncommenting 'gii' module in your `protected/config/main.php` file.

Then browse to `root-of-site/index.php?r=gii`

You can find all about `gii` here [Automatic Code Generation | The Definitive Guide to Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii)